# How to make the data access technology (Entity Framework) ignorance from the presentation layer (ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-mvc-5, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-6

**Premise:**

I am exercising Domain-Driven Design and I separate my solution into 4 layers:

- Presentation Layer

  - An ASP.NET Web API 2 project for a RESTful API web service
  - An ASP.NET Web MVC5 project for a documentation and admin screens
- Application Layer

  - A class library project responsible to take commands from presentation layer and consume any domain services
- Domain Layer

  - A class library project that contains business models and logic
  - A class library project that contains the domain services
- Infrastructure Layer

  - A class library project that contains all the concrete implementation, like dataq persistance using Entity Framework, logging using Log4net, IoC using Simple Injector, etc

The domain layer only has a set of repository interfaces defined for the aggregates and it's up to the implementation data access mechanism which exists in the infrastructure layer to hide the implementation details.

In this exercise, I decide to use Entity Framework Database first approach. And of course, there is a `app.config` in the infrastructure project that contains a connection string.

**Problems:**

Ok, I spend a great deal and time trying to separate all the concerns and to focus on domain models. In the presentation layer (i.e., the API and MVC projects), there is no direct reference to the infrastructure project. And IoC container has been setup so all concrete implementation of the required interfaces would be injected into controller constructors.

When I select, for example, the API project as start project and run it, I got

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: No connection string named 'xxxxxx' could be found in the application config file.
```

**Question:**

Now I understand if I install Entity Framework into the API project, copy and paste connection string from the `app.config` of the infrastructure project into the `web.config` of the API project, things will work. But that breaks our original purpose of separating concerns, doesn't it? If we do that, then what's the point of using Domain-Driven Design and making the data access technology ignorance from the presentation layer?

The reason we don't directly reference direct implementation of data access technology (i.e. concrete implementations that use `dbContext` and `Linq`) is that we could easily switch the underground access technology to something else.

So what would be the proper way to do it?!!

I do not want to install Entity Framework in my presentation layer, nor copy the connection string everywhere. I want all the data access and concrete implementation of repositories exist in just one library.

Comment: It isn't worth the effort to put all of the ORM data access in a repository. Separating concerns dogmatically will create more problems than it will solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Entity Framework configuration must be in the project where it is being used. This doesn't mean it's going to break your layered structure or your separation of concerns.

Comment: ".. must be in the project where it is being used." So if I have all my data access repositories in one class library, and I have several other projects that reference it, does that mean I need to put the configuration in all the projects? That means all the projects now know it's using specific technology (i.e. Entity Framework). That's breaking the SoC doesn't it? Because we want all the clients who access the data access library to have no idea what specific technology is using under. Correct?

Comment: You have to add the connection string just in the project where it is being used. The other layers/projects don't have to include that connection string.

Comment: @DavidLiang A parameter in a configuration file doesn't break separation of concerns -- it's a runtime, loose dependency, not a compile-time one. Configuration is declared besides your application's entry point, not at a project level, at least that's how it works natively in .NET.

Comment: @DavidLiang By the way, the MVC application is probably going to be hosting your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/21/library-bundle-facade/), so it will reference the Infrastructure anyway.

Comment: @guillaume31: OK I have no problem to put the connection strings in my web.config under the MVC project then. But you still need to install Entity Framework in the MVC project, otherwise it will give you an error like "error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file". My concern is, while we're trying to make the presentation persistence ignorance, it doesn't make sense to me if you still need to install EF in it.

Comment: If you want no trace of EF in your web.config file, use Code First. Regarding referencing EF in your website, I'm afraid you can't do otherwise. You need it as soon as your web project uses a class that inherits an EF class (typically, DBContext).

Answer (score 0):

Remove all entityframework elements from your app.config. Create your own connection string element and provide it to entityframework on app startup.

Comment: You meant to dynamically provide the connection string instead of to put it in the app.config / web.config? Are you sure it would work on the MVC project, for example, without installing Entity Framework there? Could you provide a simple example for that?

Comment: You still provide the connection string in your config, just remove all the entityframework spesific settings. I don't have an example with me but will post it tomorrow